# How to interpret confidence interval for multiple logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, confidence-interval

I am currently learning linear regression for binomial data and I am a bit confused in some things since this type of regression is new to me. I am mostly confused how to interpret the confidence interval for a predictor variable in multiple logistic regression.

I did logistic regression on my data using this code in R: `gml(Y~., family="binomial", data=data_train)`.
One of the predictor variables (b4) for which I am trying to interpret the confidence interval got a value of -0.304 which i transformed to odds e^(-0.304) = 0.73786. This I enterpret as:  b4 has a 26% (1 – 0.73786 = 0.26214) reduction on the response variable. Did I enterpret this right?

Next I calculated a confidence interval for b4: $$e^{\beta_j \pm z^* S E\left(\beta_j\right)}$$

and this gave me the following 90 % confidence interval: [0.168 : 8.904].
This I would interpret as: I am 90% confident that the odds ratio for b4 would be between 0-168 - 8.904. This seems as a lazy and also wrong interpretation of the confidence interval. How would you interpret this confidence interval?

Comment: What is b4? Binary? Numeric?

Comment: Numeric. beta 4 - predictor variable.

Comment: On the first glance, your calculations seem to be okay. The interpretation, however, is not correct. Regarding the confidence interval: it is very wide because, probably, your data set is very small or your model contains strongly correlated predictors. You might need to explain your model more than just doing two calculations though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Any idea where to find information on how to interpret the confidence interval?

Comment: The problem is how you interpret the effect itself. "A one-point increase in b4 is associated with a log-odds reduction of 0.3". Or: a one-point increase in b4 is associated with a 26% decrease in the odds of having event 1.